# Redirecting a link to the same page if the page of that url is already opened

Tags: redirect

This is a voicemail application. Where I have a page /faces/manageVoicemail.xhtml
Which lists all the voicemails for the logged in user.

Whenever a new voicemail comes we get a email notification. Right now, if they click on the link in the email it redirects to /faces/managevoicemail, if the user has a opened session.

Right now it opens in a new tab. The requirement is to redirect the link to the same page if that page is already open.

Comment: So you want to enumerate all active sessions within any/all open browsers and then redirect a page (if found) to the link address?

Comment: If the emails are viewed in a web-based mail client in the same browser, then maybe you can achieve this by using a `target` attribute on your links. (And perhaps having the site set `window.name` to that same value via JavaScript, when it is opened on its own.) Other than that, I doubt you can achieve this – at least not with common web technologies, it would probably rather require manipulation on the level of the applications used.

Comment: Sorry got busy with other issues..coming back to the same again. I will try it in both of your suggestions and will comeback again if I can achieve with any of these. Thanks.